# Loop through and assign values to class properties using PropertyInfo[]

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to automatically assign string values, from an array of strings, to a classes properties using a propertyinfo array.

```
Class Car
{
    public string wheels, doors, windows;
    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Car).GetProperties();
    public Car(string[] values)
    {
        int index=0;
        foreach(PropertyInfo pi in props)
        {
            pi.SetValue(pi.Name, values[index], null);
            //pi.SetValue(pi.Name, values[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error saying "Object does not match target type." I'm sure what I'm missing after seeing some other examples on Stack or other message boards.

Comment: I would actually convert that code to a static method I will post an example of what I am doing and how you can call it regardless of the Class name this way you won't have to hardcode the `typeoc(Car)` like you are doing in your code..

Answer (score 2):

I have created a `public static class Extensions` called Extensions where i have placed this code in you should be able to follow the code very easily

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void ConvertNullToStringEmpty<T>(this T clsObject) where T : class
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = clsObject.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var info in properties)
        {
            // if a string and null, set to String.Empty
            if (info.PropertyType == typeof(string) && info.GetValue(clsObject, null) == null)
            {
                info.SetValue(clsObject, String.Empty, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a shot.

Comment: @GoodBoyNYC this should work for you with one or 2 changes.. basically you can test this by creating a class.. then call the code and it basically changes all of the class auto properties when you create a new instance of the class their default properties if null will be set to string.Empty. I hope this makes sense..